# ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined on richfaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

I am needing to use a jQuery plugin in a view. But even replacing the per JQuery and using JQuery.noConflits () the plugin does not work within the view and the firebug console shows the error:

> ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined JQuery('.botao').click(function($) {

Estou carregando o JQuery antes do script que gera esse erro (acd.js):

```
    <link href="${ctx}/view/common/resources/style/acd.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="${ctx}/view/common/resources/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" >jQuery.noConflict()</script>
    <script src="${ctx}/view/common/resources/scripts/acd.js" type="text/javascript"  />
```

acd.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    JQuery('.botao').click(function($) {
[..]
```

Comment: If it isn't defined it is likely because the path to the jQuery file is not correct. Are there any other errors in your browser's console?

Comment: The JQuery is being loaded as shown in the image: http://postimg.org/image/5t8wu79vz/
No other error appears on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the capitalization of your alias, you have set it to jQuery but try to call it with JQuery -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    jQuery('.botao').click(function($) { // make the change here
[..]
```